# openvpn client in docker with centos and mikrotik server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, openvpn, openvpn-connect

I owned a openvpn server in mikrotik
i want to setup open vpn client in docker over centos
So that I can access the database on the server centos

Please guide me on how to establish a connection between the Docker as an ؤمهثىف
To connect to a server openVPN mikrotik

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

hello you need to check 2 steps:

1# configuration of cents on open VPN with due Docker client... after that just make a configuration within your mikrotik server connecting to Open VPN.

So come on...

The first thing to do is to configure the open VPN on VPN in the Cents operating system.

Follow the link with tutorial.
https://medium.com/geekculture/deploy-a-vpn-server-with-docker-9bd512f2be2b

Reference GITHUB= https://github.com/yivo/docker-centos7-openvpn

After following the setup mentioned above...

2 you must configure the VPN on mikrotik.

Follow the official link to the mikrotik website

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eVP743yMNs

With mikrotik's official video tutorial, dedicated to this question....

In this case... you should have asked a question but I understand that your objective is pluralized.
I hope it helped you!

Comment: my open vpn server is in mikrotik
i want setup open vpn client in docker over centos
to connect automatic when start 
the ca. & kay in mikrotik server openvpn was created
can you help my 
how config docker as openvpn client

Comment: that doesn't solve ? @ahmed ragaa

Comment: install and put to boot with boot